# Removing whitespace string from a string variable in php

Tags: php, ajax

I tried removing the whitespace but don´t work. I use trim for remove spaces.
I realized in php, for callback in a responseText ajax.

```
$orderHTML = $producto['id'].'#'.$producto['nombre_producto'].'*'.$producto['precioVenta'].'*'.$producto['descripcion'].'*'.$producto['descatalogado'].'@'.$producto['cantidad_stock'];
    echo trim($orderHTML);
```

In my ajax the result data is:

```
data: "        1#jeans*1.00**0@100"
```

I´ve got my call a php is:

```
GET "http://localhost:8080/ajax/products_ajax.php?idProducto=1&opcion=2"
```

My php is:

```
<?php
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once '../../config.php';
require_once '/functions/function_orders.php';
$opcion = $_REQUEST['opcion'];

switch($opcion)
{
    case '1':

        if(isset($_POST['parametro1'])&&isset($_POST['parametro2']))
        {
            $orderHTML = getOrdersProduct($_POST['parametro1'],$_POST['parametro2']);
            echo trim($orderHTML);

        }
        break;

    case '2':

        if(isset($_GET['idProducto']))
        {
            $producto = getOrdersProduct1($_GET['idProducto']);
            $orderHTML = trim($producto['id']).'#'.$producto['nombre_producto'].'*'.$producto['precioVenta'].'*'.$producto['descripcion'].'*'.$producto['descatalogado'].'@'.$producto['cantidad_stock'];
            echo trim($orderHTML);
        }

}
```

My query in idiorm:

```
 function getOrdersProduct1($identificador)
{
    return ORM::for_table('producto')->
    where('id',$identificador)->find_one()->as_array();
}
```

I realize one var_dump($productos);die();

```
array (size=11)
  'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'nombre_producto' => string 'jeans' (length=6)
  'nombre_latin' => null
  'peso' => string '100.00' (length=6)
  'descatalogado' => string '0' (length=1)
  'dimensiones' => null
  'descripcion' => null
  'cantidad_stock' => string '100' (length=3)
  'precioVenta' => string '1.00' (length=4)
  'gama_id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'proveedor_id' => string '1' (length=1)
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: where/how do you use trim? without that, we can't really help you. I'm guessing you have trimmed the id, but aren't using the trimmed copy.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing before `$producto['id']`? Show us the rest.

Comment: check the ltrim() function to remove whitespace from the beginning of a string

Comment: Your `echo trim` code is fine, the problem lies elsewhere. Check all the files you include for either having `<?php` not at the direct beginning of the file or having some whitespace after the closing `?>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the trim function with the second argument correctly. if all that fails try

```
$str = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $str));
```

the line of code will remove extra spaces, as well as leading and trailing spaces. this is combined with trim and preg_replace.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that your $producto['id'] is a text field of fixed length and therefore has leading spaces.

You should use `trim()` or `ltrim()` to remove these before concatenating the values into the `$orderHTML`, then later when you come to read the code it will be self documenting as to why you had to do this manipulation, like so

```
$orderHTML = ltrim($producto['id']) . '#' .
                   $producto['nombre_producto'].'*'.
                   $producto['precioVenta'].'*'.
                   $producto['descripcion'].'*'.
                   $producto['descatalogado'].'@'.
                   $producto['cantidad_stock'];

echo $orderHTML;
```

Comment: You have changed your question since I gave this answer